# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class <clase> could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación sencilla con php y mysql. Al momento de hacer al conexión a la bd me arroja el error

> Object of class conexion could not be converted to string.

El código de la conexión es el siguiente:

```
    <?php

    class conexion extends PDO{

    private $servidor = "localhost";
    private $usuario = "root";
    private $contrasenia = "";
    private $conexion;    

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
           $this -> conexion = new PDO("mysql:host = $this-> servidor; dbname = album", $this -> usuario, $this -> contrasenia);

           $this -> conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

           $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
        } catch (PDOException $error) {
             
            return $error;
        }    
    }    

    public function ejecutar($sql){        

        $this -> conexion -> exec($sql);
        
        return $this->conexion->lastInsertId();
    }
    
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No podes utilizar la sintaxis `$this->servidor` dentro de una cadena.

El compilador entiende que tiene que convertir `$this` a texto y por esto que obtienes ese error.

#### Solución:

Hay varias opciones pero la más simple, concatenar la cadena:

```php
$this->conexion = new PDO(
    "mysql:host = " . $this->servidor . ", dbname=album", 
    $this->usuario, 
    $this->contrasenia
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funcionó ;))

Comment: no coloquen espacios en la sintaxis de php cuando usen flechas simples